# Infragistics Documentation

Tags: infragistics

We have used Infragistics controls in our applications for years. However, we have always had a hard time getting started using controls, because of the samples and documentation.  For those of you that use Infragistics controls, what is the best way you have found to use the samples and documentation?  For those of you that do not, what other control packages have you found that have good documentation and are easy to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have to be honest say that we gave up on the Infragistics stuff a few years back.

We flirted with ComponentArt then settled on the [TeleRik controls](http://www.telerik.com/), mainly because of ease of use, flexibility and the documentation is pretty good.

Comment: It looks like we are giving up on Infragistics as well.

Answer (score 3):

Been working with Infragistics stuff for awhile now. Usually I check out the samples to see what the controls can do, then when I need something specific, if I can't easily find it perusing with the object browser, then I simply ask their support. They are quick to respond and know their stuff like expected.

You can also search their forums but I find it lacks content; maybe because most of their users prefer asking the support staff.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure, if you are still using Infragistics, but the link to their online documentation is [here](http://www.infragistics.com/help/online-documentation/)

Answer (score 1):

I've used [ComponentArt](http://www.componentart.com/default.aspx) and they have pretty decent api docs